# Sagemaker pipelines - popping out X from the pipeline since it will be overriden

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

Since upgrading [sagemaker](https://pypi.org/project/sagemaker) to `2.173+` logs got a bit noisy. When evaluating the Sagemaker Pipeline, I'm seeing plenty of

```
WARNING:sagemaker.workflow.utilities:Popping out 'ProcessingJobName' from the pipeline definition by default since it will be overridden at pipeline execution time. Please utilize the PipelineDefinitionConfig to persist this field in the pipeline definition if desired.
WARNING:sagemaker.workflow.utilities:Popping out 'ProcessingJobName' from the pipeline definition by default since it will be overridden at pipeline execution time. Please utilize the PipelineDefinitionConfig to persist this field in the pipeline definition if desired.
WARNING:sagemaker.workflow.utilities:Popping out 'TrainingJobName' from the pipeline definition by default since it will be overridden at pipeline execution time. Please utilize the PipelineDefinitionConfig to persist this field in the pipeline definition if desired.
WARNING:sagemaker.workflow._utils:Popping out 'CertifyForMarketplace' from the pipeline definition since it will be overridden in pipeline execution time.
WARNING:sagemaker.workflow.utilities:Popping out 'ModelPackageName' from the pipeline definition by default since it will be overridden at pipeline execution time. Please utilize the PipelineDefinitionConfig to persist this field in the pipeline definition if desired.
```

with the emphasis on `Please utilize the PipelineDefinitionConfig to persist this field in the pipeline definition if desired`. However, I can't find how to actually use that `PipelineDefinitionConfig` in the [documentation](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/workflows/pipelines/sagemaker.workflow.pipelines.html#pipeline-definition-config), nor any example on github.

Any references how to *resolve* these warning without just suppressing them?

Comment: I have the same warning but with other arguments: ProcessingJobName, TrainingJobName and ModelPackageName. The curiosity is that I'm not setting any of this arguments explicitly. The warnings are raised when upserting the pipeline object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [access management documentation for pipelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/build-and-manage-access.html#build-and-manage-step-permissions-prefix) has a more thorough explanation:

> Job prefixing is off by default. To opt into this feature, use the use_custom_job_prefix option of PipelineDefinitionConfig as shown in the following snippet:

```
# Create a definition configuration and toggle on custom prefixing
definition_config = PipelineDefinitionConfig(use_custom_job_prefix=True);

# Create a pipeline with a custom prefix
 pipeline = Pipeline(
     name="MyJobPrefixedPipeline",
     parameters=[...]
     steps=[...]
     pipeline_definition_config=definition_config
)
```

The warnings seem to be purely informational. You can opt into job prefixing using the example above to make them go away, or just ignore them.

Comment: That got rid of warnings on job names. `CertifyForMarketplace` is still there unfortunately.

Comment: Annoying caveat: once custome job prefix is enabled, all jobs MUST be passed custom job names.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That piece of documentation is not easy to find at all, and the last thing one would expect is that job names are used for IAM...

Comment: Thanks! That documentation page is a hidden gem!